# Getting a random crash on iOS MarketingCloud/SFMC SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios

I recently updated to the Marketing Cloud v8.0.6 and SFMC v1.0.4. I am able to receive pushes but every once in a while will get a crash when setting the `URLHandlingDelegate`. Here is my current implementation

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface AppDelegate (MarketingCloud)<SFMCSdkURLHandlingDelegate>

- (void)registerForPushNotification;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```
#import "AppDelegate+MarketingCloud.h"

@implementation AppDelegate (PushNotifications)

- (void)registerForPushNotification {
    [self configureMarketingCloudSDK];
}

-(BOOL) configureMarketingCloudSDK {
    
    NSString *appID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Marketing Cloud App Id"];
    NSString *accessToken = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Marketing Cloud Token"];
    NSString *appEndpoint = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Marketing Cloud Endpoint"];
    NSString *mid = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Marketing Cloud MID"];
    
    PushConfigBuilder *builder = [[PushConfigBuilder alloc] initWithAppId:appID];
    builder = [builder setAccessToken:accessToken];
    builder = [builder setMarketingCloudServerUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:appEndpoint]];
    builder = [builder setMid:mid];
    builder = [builder setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet:TRUE];
    builder = [builder setInboxEnabled:FALSE];
    builder = [builder setLocationEnabled:FALSE];
    builder = [builder setAnalyticsEnabled:TRUE];
    PushConfig *configuration = [builder build];
    
    void (^completion)(OperationResult) = ^(OperationResult result){
        if (result == OperationResultSuccess) {
            [self setupMobilePush];
        }
    };
    
    SFMCSdkConfigBuilder *configBuilder = [[SFMCSdkConfigBuilder alloc] init];
    configBuilder = [configBuilder setPushWithConfig:configuration onCompletion:completion];
    
    [SFMCSdk initializeSdk:[configBuilder build]];
    
    return TRUE;
}

- (void)setupMobilePush {
    if (SFMCSdk.mp.getStatus == ModuleStatusOperational) {
        #if TEST
            [SFMCSdk setLoggerWithLogLevel:SFMCSdkLogLevelDebug logOutputter:[[SFMCSdkLogOutputter alloc] init]];
        #endif
        [[SFMCSdk mp] setURLHandlingDelegate:self];
    }
}

- (void)sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL * _Nonnull)url type:(NSString * _Nonnull)type {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url] == true) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if (success) {
                
            }
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

SDK State

```
SDK State = {

  "modules" : {

    "cdp" : {

      "compatibility" : "1.9.0 - 2.9.9",

      "name" : "cdp",

      "pendingOperations" : "undefined",

      "status" : "inactive",

      "version" : "unavailable"

    },

    "push" : {

      "compatibility" : "8.0.2 - 8.9.9",

      "name" : "push",

      "pendingOperations" : "0",

      "properties" : {

        "details" : "{\n  \"Notifications Details\" : {\n    \"Last Notification Received\" : \"None\"\n  },\n  \"Retry Alarms Active\" : [\n    \"SFMCRegistration\",\n    \"SFMCDeviceStatsItemEntity\",\n    \"MarketingCloudSDKIntelligenceSendPIAnalyticsSystem\"\n  ],\n  \"iOS Data Protection\" : {\n    \"Protected Data Available\" : \"true\",\n    \"File Protection Type\" : {\n      \"NSURLFileProtectionKey\" : \"NSURLFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"In-App Message Details\" : {\n    \"Current In-App Messages\" : \"None\",\n    \"Current In-App Triggers\" : \"None\",\n    \"Custom In-App Message Font\" : \"None\"\n  },\n  \"Control Channel Details\" : {\n    \"Last Control Channel Payload Received\" : \"No Data\"\n  },\n  \"Analytics Details\" : {\n    \"useLegacyPiIdentifier\" : false,\n    \"PiIdentifier\" : \"Not Set\",\n    \"PIAnalyticsEnabled\" : false,\n    \"ETAnalyticsEnabled\" : true\n  },\n  \"MarketingCloudSDK General Information\" : {\n    \"MarketingCloudSDKLocationDelegate\" : \"Not set\",\n    \"MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate\" : \"Not set\",\n    \"MarketingCloudSDKEventDelegate\" : \"Not set\",\n    \"Push Information\" : {\n      \"Developer has Push Enabled\" : \"Yes\",\n      \"User has Push Enabled\" : \"Yes\",\n      \"Quiet Push Enabled\" : \"No\",\n      \"Device Token\" : \"Not yet set\"\n    },\n    \"MarketingCloudSDK Configuration Details\" : {\n      \"Current Configuration\" : {\n        \"appid\" : \"3B87E9FF-1DA3-4FAF-82D7-11D5E354D1AE\",\n        \"mid\" : \"500009926\",\n        \"inbox\" : false,\n        \"location\" : false,\n        \"etanalytics\" : true,\n        \"delayregistrationuntilcontactkeyisset\" : true,\n        \"accesstoken\" : \"SccRcfu7UY0VNXmpnfoAKHOo\",\n        \"marketing_cloud_server_url\" : \"https:\\\/\\\/mc2jrshflxy42kr5yph0mq-yzsdq.device.marketingcloudapis.com\\\/\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"Device Details\" : {\n      \"OS Version\" : \"15.4\",\n      \"Hardware Description\" : \"x86_64\",\n      \"Device Reported Timezone\" : \"3600\",\n      \"Device Locale\" : \"en_US\",\n      \"DeviceId\" : \"E533F8A9-BB2B-479F-AC87-6E8E5990AE8B\",\n      \"Daylight Savings Time Active\" : true,\n      \"Platform Name\" : \"iOS\"\n    },\n    \"Application Name\" : \"BAExec\",\n    \"Registration Details\" : {\n      \"Date of Last Successful Registration\" : \"None\",\n      \"Subscriber Token\" : \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cGUiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tIiwiY29udGFjdEtleSI6IkNQTS0wMDAwMDA3NTY3MTUiLCJvcmRpbmFsIjozLCJleHAiOjE2NTU1MTU1MDF9.TfaGJujpw6n-dxHakfYTdCTJs8PVnQj6FcC-7eclUfw\",\n      \"Current Registration\" : {\n        \"sdk_Version\" : \"8.0.6\",\n        \"dST\" : true,\n        \"subscriberKey\" : \"CPM-000000756715\",\n        \"location_Enabled\" : true,\n        \"etAppId\" : \"3B87E9FF-1DA3-4FAF-82D7-11D5E354D1AE\",\n        \"platform_Version\" : \"15.4\",\n        \"quietPushEnabled\" : false,\n        \"tags\" : [\n          \"ALL\",\n          \"IOS\",\n          \"iPhone\"\n        ],\n        \"locale\" : \"en_US\",\n        \"proximity_Enabled\" : true,\n        \"registrationId\" : \"E533F8A9-BB2B-479F-AC87-6E8E5990AE8B\",\n        \"platform\" : \"iOS\",\n        \"timeZone\" : \"3600\",\n        \"hwid\" : \"x86_64\",\n        \"push_Enabled\" : \"true\",\n        \"deviceID\" : \"E533F8A9-BB2B-479F-AC87-6E8E5990AE8B\",\n        \"app_Version\" : \"4.0.5\"\n      },\n      \"Last Successfully Sent Registration\" : \"None\"\n    },\n    \"Application Version\" : \"Version 4.0.5 (Build 1)\",\n    \"MarketingCloudSDK Version\" : \"8.0.6\"\n  },\n  \"Privacy Settings\" : {\n    \"Privacy Mode\" : \"SFMCPrivacyModeNotBlocked\"\n  }\n}"

      },

      "status" : "operational",

      "version" : "8.0.6"

    }

  },

  "registrationId" : "E533F8A9-BB2B-479F-AC87-6E8E5990AE8B",

  "version" : "1.0.4"

}
```

This is the line that the crash happens on

```
[[SFMCSdk mp] setURLHandlingDelegate:self];
```

I believe the implementation is correct since I am getting pushes. One of the reasons I think it might be crashing is that I implemented it in obj-c instead of Swift. I needed to do this though since out `AppDelegate` is also written in obj-c.

I currently don't have a stack of the crash but can add it here later if I can reproduce it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[SFMCSdk mp] setURLHandlingDelegate:self];

The above line has a direct reference to self which is accessed inside the block which holds the reference and may cause the bad access issues.
Request to have the self to be weakpointer ifhaving to access the self within block. Please note that this is nothing to have to be done with SDK.

Thanks
Prakashini